# Visual Studio Code blurred

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI3J2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w28kq.png)

This month I started having this problem with VSCode, the entire window becomes blurry or sometimes just some areas. I tried Android Studio and it works fine, Apache NetBeans also works fine. I already updated VSCode but the problem continues. It is not a physical problem with the screen, I play without problems and only in this problem does this happen to me.

Version: 1.86.2 (user setup)
Commit: 903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda
Date: 2024-02-13T19:40:56.878Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26908389
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.23620

I have updated the graphics driver. I updated VSCode. I've tried other display settings including scaling but the problem is not with video or display, it's just in VSCode